# Access modifiers within a method

Tags: java, methods, access-modifiers

Is it **absolutely** illegal to use access modifiers (public / private / protected) on variables declared in a Java method? Is there any exceptional case whereby we are allow to use access modifiers on variables declared within a method?

**Example 1:**

```
public class myclass
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    public int number = 0; //This will cause an error (illegal start of expression)
  }

}
```

**Example 2:**

```
public class myclass
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {

  }
  public static void myMethod()
  {
    public int number = 0; //This will cause an error (illegal start of expression)
  }
}
```

This question may sound simple for many, but I wanted to know how absolute is it that we cannot use access modifiers in a method. Is it absolutely impossible?

Comment: Why you want to do that? Aren't instances good enough?

Comment: Relevant documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's illegal for a local variable to have any access modifier: `public`, `protected`, or `private`.

The [JLS, Section 14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4), defines what can be a part of a local variable declaration, and it doesn't include access modifiers: only an annotation and/or `final`.

> LocalVariableDeclaration:
>
> {VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList

and

> VariableModifier:
>
> Annotation final

Also, local variables' scopes are already limited to the block in which they're declared.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are always visible within the scope they are created, access modifiers just don't make any sense there. There are no circumstances or special cases where they are allowed.

Access modifiers can only me applied to variables on the instance or class level.

You can check the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) for the specification of local variable declarations to see that this is never allowed by the syntax rules:

> *A local variable declaration statement declares one or more local variable names.*

```
...
LocalVariableDeclaration:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators

VariableModifiers:
    VariableModifier
    VariableModifiers VariableModifier

VariableModifier: one of
    Annotation final
...
```

Here you clearly see that `final` is the only modifier allowed before a local variable aside from annotations.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am wondering is there any rare/ particular case it might make some sense.

Comment: @user3437460: No, there are not.